# How to derive a class from a nested interface?

Tags: c#

The following code is not compilable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }
    }

    class Class : Class.Interface
    {
        internal interface Interface
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> error CS0146: Circular base class dependency involving 'ConsoleApplication1.Class' and 'ConsoleApplication1.Class.Interface'

Don't understand this.

Update: 
This is probably more "motivating" (-;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }
    }


    class Container : Container.Interface
    {
        // Everything, that is of type "Container.Interface" can be used as child here. 
        // ... including the container itself. 
        Interface[] _children;

        // Is nested to keep the naming consistent. 
        internal interface Interface
        {}
    }
}
```

Wenn I put the interface outside of class "Container", it should be named somthing like "ContainerChildInterface". In my project I will have several classes like this, and thus several interfaces. And I think, using nested interfaces would be much better style in this case.

Comment: How can you implement something that you are defining within yourself?

Comment: Perhaps you should demonstrate why it is a good solution in this complex project. I see no reason you can't make the interface internal without it being nested.

Comment: I think your understanding of interfaces is a little lacking. The primary purpose of an interface is to tell code that calls your class what it can expect in terms of methods. Just call it IContainer and make it an internal interface outside of Container.

Comment: Nick explained it perfectly in his answer. A class cannot be labeled as having an interface if that interface hasn't been created yet. There is absolutely no reason for your desired arrangement aside from the dot naming structure, which is itself a bad style.